# Microsoft Multilingual illegal characters in path on build

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, compiler-errors, multilingual

I am trying to install the Visual Studio 2017 extension Multiligual App ToolKit 4.0. everything installed correctly and i managed to get some translation but when ever i go to build my app i get this error

Description:
"illegal Characters in path."

File:
"Microsoft.Multilingual.ResxResources.targets"

Line: 32

this is line 32:

```
<MultilingualBuild
      ContinueOnError="ErrorAndContinue"
      AppName="$(MSBuildProjectName)"
      ProjectPath="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"
      SourceCulture="$(DefaultLanguage)"
      EmbeddedResource="@(EmbeddedResource);@(Content)"
      XliffResource="@(XliffResource)"
      None="@(None)"
      BuildServerInfo="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)"
      CachePath="$(IntermediateOutputPath)"
      HasSharedItems="$(HasSharedItems)"
      MSBuildAllProjects="$(MSBuildAllProjects)"
      TranslationReport="$(TranslationReport)"
      SuppressPseudoWarning="$(SuppressPseudoWarning)"
      />
```

it is within this node

```
<Target Name="MultilingualAppToolkit" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild" Condition="'$(IsCrossTargetingBuild)' != 'true' AND '$(IsWpfTempProject)' != 'true' ">
```

has anyone had this problem before or know where/how i can start to debug?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fixed this by removing the Xamarin.LiveReload Nuget package.